# get_next_line implementation in C

Tags: c, free

I am trying to implement `get_next_line`, a function that enables me to read a file one line at a time until `EOF`, and store the lines in a table of pointers, `**line`.
Here is my code:

```
int ft_fill_line(char **s, char **line)
{
    char *tmp;
    int len;

    len = 0;
    while ((*s)[len] != '\n' && (*s)[len])
        len++;
    if((*s)[len] == '\n')
    {
        *line = ft_substr(*s, 0, len);
        tmp = ft_strdup((*s) + len + 1);
        free((*s));
        (*s) = tmp;
        if ((*s)[0] == '\0')
        {
            free(*s);
            s = NULL;
        }
    }
    else if ((*s)[len] == '\0')
    {
        *line = ft_strdup(*s);
        free(*s);
        s = NULL;
    }
    return (1);
}

int     get_next_line(int fd, char **line)
{
    static char *s;
    char buf[BUFFER_SIZE +1];
    char *tmp;
    int ret;

    if (fd < 0 || line == NULL)
        return (-1);
    while ((ret = read(fd, buf, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0)
    {
        buf[ret] = '\0';
        if (s == NULL)
            s = ft_strnew(1);
        tmp = ft_strjoin(s, buf);
        free(s);
        s = tmp;
        if (ft_strchr(buf, '\n'))
            break;
    }
    if (ret < 0)
        return(-1);
    else if (ret == 0 && (s == NULL || s[0] == '\0'))
        return (0);
    return (ft_fill_line(&s, line));
}
```

`ft_substr` being a program that truncates a string, `ft_strjoin` a program that joins two strings, `ft_strnew` a program that allocates a new string of the size it takes as input, `ft_strchr` a function that searches a character in a string and returns a pointer to it.

When I compile, I keep getting the following error : "pointer being freed was not allocated".  I can fix this error when I set my `static s` to NULL at the beginning of my `function get_next_line`, yet when I do that my program modifies the content of the file that is read.

Here is my `main.c`:

```
int main(void)
{
    int fd;
    char **line;
    int ret;

    fd = open("text.txt", O_RDONLY);
    if (!(line = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*) * 10000)))
        return (0);

    while ((ret = get_next_line(fd, line)) > 0)
    {
        printf("%s\n", *line);
        printf("%i\n", ret);
        free(*line);
    }
    printf("%s\n", *line);
    printf("%i\n", ret);
    free(line);
    return(0);
```

}

Does anyone know what's wrong with my program? It seems to me that `s` is always allocated before I free it.

Comment: You should probably also do something like `line[i] = (char*)malloc(max_len+1)` for each one of your 10000 lines.

Comment: And of course, you should also do `free(line[i])` for each one of them towards the end of your program.

Comment: regarding: `if (!(line = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*) * 10000)))
        return (0);`  In general, a returned value from `main()` of 0 indicates Success. and when an error occurs, should output to `stderr` your error message and if the error is from a C library function should output to `stderr` the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  The function: `perror()` does all that.  Then call: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE);` to exit the program.  In C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code.

Comment: regarding: `if (!(line = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*) * 10000)))`   Suggest calling `calloc()` rather than `malloc()` so all the pointers in `line[]`  are already NULL

Comment: OT:  regarding: `fd = open("text.txt", O_RDONLY);`  always check (>0) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful.  Call: `perror( "open failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  also at any program after that, call `close( fd );` before exiting the program.

Comment: The posted code does not compile!  it is missing the needed `#include` statements for the needed header files

Comment: the function: `get_next_line()` seems to be trying to replace the C library function: `fgets()`.  Is that what your trying to do?